# Discussion: Laravel Eloquent vs DB queries for appends

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have a use case where I have some models (more than 20+) one of those models has relations with 15 other models, there are also some traits which have some appends in them.

I would like to get opinions on how should those queries run:

> Sum some field on products table:

Should I use this syntacs:

```
$this->products()->sum('someField')
```

or should I use:

```
DB::table('products')->sum('someField')
```

It may be the same but I am not so sure, I am asking this because performance is very important and every ms save will be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably use `DB::table()`

The rule of thumb with Eloquent as well as any other ORM is that there is a lot of overhead in creating and "hydrating" objects, even worse if there are related tables with objects being queried and created.  If all you need to do here is get a sum, then you avoid the overhead of the ORM.

With that said, the code to generate a sum should be similar in this case, if not a micro-optimization, because you are using a model class, so you're not hydrating an object or collection of objects.

You can always benchmark the two different approaches with your system/data. Either way you do it, sum is a SQL aggregate that's going to generate similar or exactly the same SQL and return you a number and not an object, where concerns about hydration and population of collections of related objects might be queried for by the ORM.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of large data, query builder is faster and better in terms of performance, but if you are just interested in one record or few records, eloquent is preferable.

If you are looking for better relationship, Eloquent is better than query builder.

In you case, you are more interested with speed, your best option is query builder

```
DB::table('products')->sum('someField')
```